# Able to push to remote repository without Github authentication

Tags: github

Whenever I push to a remote repository, GitHub does not ask me for authentication. What is going on ?

Comment: Your credentials were stored the first time you pushed to your repository.

Comment: how do I turn it off ?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git